# hvplot: Creating border around plot

Tags: bokeh, hvplot

I want to create a plot using hvplot that has a border around all four sides, like the default style of matplotlib when I'm using Jupyter notebook. Example:[image]

However, using hvplot, whether I use extension("bokeh") or extension("matplotlib"), the plots come out with no border:

[image]

I tried opts(border = 1), but this doesn't have the desired effect.

Is there a way for hvplot to output a plot with a border around all four sides like matplotlib?

Comment: The plot above does have a border on all four sides, it's just light grey. Are you saying you want to make it darker? The relevant Bokeh plot properties are `outline_line_color` and `outline_line_width`. I don't know how to configure those from `hvplot` though.

Comment: I see the outline too! Could be a monitor setting. Bokeh opts can be set on hvPlot output as described at https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html#setting-backend-opts

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar

I tried to replicate the example from that page:

`import holoviews as hv 

import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np 

from holoviews import dim, opts 

hv.extension("bokeh") 

data = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.arange(-10,10,0.1),"y":10*np.arange(-10,10,0.1)}) 

hv.Curve(data).opts( backend_opts={"plot.toolbar.autohide": True} ) 

`

However, I get the following error:

`Unexpected option 'backend_opts' for Curve type across all extensions. Similar options for current extension ('bokeh') are: ['backend'].`

Sorry, can't figure out how to newline correctly here

Comment: You'll need holoviews 1.17.0 or later. https://holoviews.org/releases.html#version-1-17-0